# Registro duplicado en consulta SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta consulta de SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS registros, DATE(fechaValidacion) AS fecha, nodo_id,motivorechazo_id
FROM registro AS r INNER JOIN prueba AS p 
GROUP BY nodo_id,fecha,motivorechazo_id 
ORDER BY fecha, nodo_id,motivorechazo_id;
```

El cual arroja un resultado duplicado por cada **motivorechazo_id**

```
#      fecha    nodo_id motivorechazo_id
1578 2019-07-24  403    1
789  2019-07-24  403    1
7    2019-07-24  403    4
14   2019-07-24  403    4
4    2019-07-24  403    5
2    2019-07-24  403    5
104  2019-07-24  403    8
208  2019-07-24  403    8
14   2019-07-24  403    9
28   2019-07-24  403    9
10   2019-07-24  403    10
```

Como se evidencia se duplica el id del motivo del rechazo y por ende la cantidad de registros que se presentaron por día. Ya en el query tengo la sentencia DISTINCT. Y con eso aún me trae registros duplicados y he de señalar que sin el DISTINCT la cantidad de registros duplicados seria aún mayor.

Lo ideal seria que aparezca así

```
    #      fecha    nodo_id motivorechazo_id
    789  2019-07-24  403    1
    14   2019-07-24  403    4
    2    2019-07-24  403    5
    208  2019-07-24  403    8
    28   2019-07-24  403    9
    10   2019-07-24  403    10
```

La estructura de las tablas son

```
---------------------            ----------------
|   Registro         |            |   Prueba     |
---------------------            ----------------
| id                 |            | id           |
---------------------            ----------------
| placa              |            | placa        |
---------------------            ----------------
| fecha              |            | estado_id    |
---------------------            ----------------
| nodo_id            |            | usuario_id   |
--------------------            ----------------
| tipoinfraccion_id  |            | velocidad    |
---------------------            ----------------
| velocidad          |            | registro_id  |
---------------------           ------------------ 
| video_id           |           | imagenprincipal |
---------------------          ---------------------
                                 | fechaValidacion |
                                --------------------
```

Y con datos sería.
[image: Registro]

[image: Prueba]

Comment: Los quieres diferentes solo por motivo rechazo o tambien por fecha y nodo??

Comment: Por fecha y nodo y que aparezca el id del motivo del rechazo

Comment: Publica la estructura de las tablas, tienes un fallo en tu join, no indicas porque registro se van a juntar las tablas

Comment: Ya agrege la estructura de la tabla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya logre solucionar el problema

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS registros, r.id,nodo_id, DATE(fechaValidacion) AS fecha_registros,motivorechazo_id 
FROM prueba AS p 
INNER JOIN registro AS r ON r.id = p.registro_id 
GROUP BY fecha_registros,nodo_id 
ORDER BY fecha,nodo_id
```

Es muy simple, el alias de FechaValidacion que le puse fue **fecha** y en un campo de la tabla registro ya habia un campo de nombre **fecha** por lo tanto esta generaba conflicto. Simplemente coloque un alies diferente

Answer (score 1):

Como ha comentado [@juandej18](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288317/registro-duplicado-en-consulta-sql/288336#comment529132_288317), es probable que el omitir como se unen las tablas `registro` y `prueba` este provocando que se dupliquen los registros.

Modifica tu consulta y agrega como se unen ambas tablas:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS registros,
  DATE(fechaValidacion) AS fecha,
  nodo_id,
  motivorechazo_id
FROM registro AS r
  INNER JOIN prueba AS p 
    ON p.registro_id = r.id -- AQUI indicamos como se unen
GROUP BY
  nodo_id,
  fecha,
  motivorechazo_id
ORDER BY
  fecha,
  nodo_id,
  motivorechazo_id;
```

Comment: No funciona, solo trae 1 registro por dia si se comparas las ids

Comment: @Alezco05, ¿podrías compartirnos unos cuantos registros de los que actualmente tienen las tablas? Puedes modificar los datos sensibles, solo importa saber si para cada registro el la tabla `registro`, existe al menos uno en `prueba`